# User right in mounted hdd (manjaro)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount

I have a mounted hard disk on my laptop with some nodejs, ... project but frequently the rights on node_modules is not good.

I mount my hdd automatically (last line) :

```
# etc/fstab
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=E2B0-CA74  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       2
UUID=7577352d-44e3-4ebb-9dad-cdf7b06a5259       /       ext4    defaults,noatime        0       1
UUID=e61277cf-d3b3-4302-ac22-6bd61d198940       swap    swap    defaults,noatime        0       2
/dev/sda1       /home/hadock/samus/     ext4    users   0       0
```

Actually i have one work around for this "problem" :

I'm go to "kde partition manager" and i unmount / mount the disk...

But a better solution is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okai i'm change the `fstab` like this and everything is fine :

from

```
# <file system>     <mount point>         <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
/dev/sda1           /home/hadock/samus/   ext4    users      0       0
```

to

```
# <file system>     <mount point>         <type>  <options>             <dump>  <pass>
/dev/sda1           /home/hadock/samus/   ext4    defaults,noatime      0       0
```